# Java windowBuilder - How can I show "File already exists" warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, savefiledialog, windowbuilder

I'm implementing file save using Jfilechooser in "window builder".

I am able to save the file with a name entered by the user, but how can I display the warning "FileName already exists"  or give an option to "OverRide the existing files".

Any ideas on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: `JCheckBox` could be used as a `Override exist file` or you can use a `JOptionPane`  to show a message to the user.  See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File chooser propably gets only path so I think you should consider something like this:

```
  File f = new File(filePathString);
  if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
     // show dialog "file exists"
  }
```

Comment: Hi I'm a newbie to windowbuilder, how do I show a dialogue box ?

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FileName already exists..") will this do ? Please help me out

Comment: Yes, I think this should work, instead of asking you should try it out :)